# How to make onClick event in NavBar in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm making my first react project. I'm new in JS, HTML, CSS and even web app programming.

What I'm trying to do is to display some information on button click.

I have my main default component, **`App.js`**. It looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar";
import "./Styles/App.css";
import ProjectsList from "./Components/Projects/ProjectsList";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    projects: [], //i get it from api on Didmount();
    showProjects: true //hardcoded var to shows projects list
  };

  componentDidMount() {
      //i get projects here from axios and my api, it works ok!
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar />
        {this.state.showProjects && (
          <ProjectsList projects={this.state.projects} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

As you can see, I can manipulate my `ProjectLists` visibility by hard-coded `showprojects` boolean. It works ok. When false it is not visible and when true it is visible, pretty simple.

How to transfer that `showProjects` variable to my `Navbar.js` component and trigger it by clicking on Navbar item?

My **`Navbar.js`**:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";

class NavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar inverse collapseOnSelect>
        <Navbar.Collapse>
          <Navbar.Form>
            <Navbar.Brand> Projects </Navbar.Brand> //button click here, how to?
          </Navbar.Form>         
        </Navbar.Collapse>
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
}

export default NavBar;
```

And view look like this:

[image]

I want to have option to click on `Projects` on my Navbar, then my `ShowProjects` will be set to true and projects will be visible. How to do that?

Thanks for any advices!

**EDIT:**

If it will help, my **`ProjectsList.js`** component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Project from "./Project";
import { ListGroup } from "react-bootstrap";

class ProjectsList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ListGroup>
        {this.props.projects.map(project => {
          return <Project project={project} key={project.id} />;
        })}
      </ListGroup>
    );
  }
}

export default ProjectsList;
```

Comment: So you want the button to toggle the boolean value of the `showProjects` state property between `true` and `false` or?

Comment: Thanks for your intrest. I have a navbar. In default, i want to that projects list hided. I want to have option to click on `Projects` label on my Navbar. When i click on it, i want to project's list to appear (make it visible). How do that?

Comment: It can be toggle button as you mentioned. But that button should be on my Navbar. I want to have an option to make projects list visible from my navbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create a state change function in the parent component:

```
toggleShowProjects = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showProjects: !prevState.showProjects
    }))
  }
```

Than pass the function to your Navbar component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Navbar from "./Components/Navbar";
import "./Styles/App.css";
import ProjectsList from "./Components/Projects/ProjectsList";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    projects: [], //i get it from api on Didmount();
    showProjects: true //hardcoded var to shows projects list
  };

  componentDidMount() {
      //i get projects here from axios and my api, it works ok!
  }
toggleShowProjects = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          showProjects: !prevState.showProjects
        }))
      }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Navbar 
        toggleProjects={this.toggleShowProjects} />
        {this.state.showProjects && (
          <ProjectsList  
          projects={this.state.projects} />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what about my `NavBar.js`? Im pretty new in react in js  and i need more detailed answer :/ For now (in this state from my original post), `Projects` label in my `Navbar` is not clickable

Comment: In your navbar, on the element you want to click, add an onClick and pass it the toggleProjects function as a prop. `onClick={this.props.toggleProjects}`